# how to draw view over lock screen in android 8.0 oreo device

Tags: android

i m trying to put window manager( using service not activity) over lockscreen and it works fine in other device except oreo device...in oreo device it display after lock screen.here is my permision foe window manager..so please suggest other solution to resolve the issue.

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            LAYOUT_FLAG = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY;

```
    } else {
        LAYOUT_FLAG = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR;

    }

    mParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LAYOUT_FLAG,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN  | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    mParams.gravity = Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL;
    mParams.screenOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
```

Comment: have the same problem. did you manage to resolve it?

Comment: Were you able to solve it? Somehow Truecaller still works fine in Android O.